# JSON, Javascript & Dynamically Created & Populated Tables

Tags: javascript, database, json, html

I've got the following JSON structure that defines a table and it's data.

```
var arrTable = 
  [{"table": "tblConfig",
  "def":
    [{"column": "Property", "type": "TEXT NOT NULL"},
     {"column": "Value",    "type": "TEXT NOT NULL"}],
  "data":
    [{"Property": "VersionNumber", "Value": "1.0"},
     {"Property": "ReleaseDate",   "Value": "2010-01-01"}]
  }]
```

The code describes a table named "tblConfig" with two columns, "Property" and "Value" both are type "TEXT NOT NULL". The table has two rows of data.

```
Property_______Value_____
VersionNumber  1.0
ReleaseDate    2010-01-01
```

Below is my Javascript code to create and populate the table. It builds the create table SQL great but I'm having trouble with the populate function.

```
dbController.updateDatabase = function () {
  this.db.transaction(function (transaction) {
//load data.json
    var dbDefs = dbController.jsonObject(url + "data.json")
//parse array "table"
    eval(dbDefs);
    for (var i in arrTables) {
      createTable(arrTables[i].table, arrTables[i].def, arrTables[i].data);
    }
//create table
    function createTable(table, arrDef, arrData) {
      var arrColumns = [];
      var strSQL = "CREATE TABLE " + table + " (";
      for (var j in arrDef) {
        arrColumns.push(arrDef[j].column);
        strSQL += arrDef[j].column + " " + arrDef[j].type + ", ";
      }
      strSQL = strSQL.substring(0, strSQL.lastIndexOf(",")) + ")";
      transaction.executeSql(strSQL, [],
        function () {
          console.log(table + " created.");
          populateTable(table, arrData);
          return;
        },
        dbController.errorHandler
      );
    }
//populate table
    function populateTable(table, arrData) {
      ...
    }
  });
};
```

I want to be able to get the column names ("Property" & "Value") out of the "data" object and use them in the insert SQL string. I thought something like this would work.

```
//populate table
    function populateTable(table, arrColumns, arrData) {
      var strVal;
      var arrVal;
      for (var k in arrData) {
        strVal = "?,";
        arrVal.push(arrData[k]. ~~ KEY VALUE NAME ~~ )
      }
      var strSQL = "INSERT INTO " + table + " (" + strCol + ") ";
      strSQL += "VALUES (" + strVal.lastIndexOf(",") + ");";
      transaction.executeSql(strSQL, arrVal, null, dbController.errorHandler);
      console.log("  " + table + " populated.");
    }
```

The bugger is the **bolded** statement. I've tried using .hasOwnProperty() on arrData but that only returns 0 and 1, not the words "Property" and "Value". I don't want to use the "arrData[k].Property" notation because there are many more tables in the schema and I don't want to write create and insert statements for each table.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

---

Thanks to everyone for their help and head-scratching due to my late-night post. My intention with this function was to have a JSON object that defined multiple tables and held the table's data. Since none of the tables have the same number of columns or column names I had to devise a way of getting the data out of "data" without using the `object.member` syntax. I had forgotten about the `object["member"]` syntax.
Here's the solution.

```
dbController.updateDatabase = function (a) {
  this.db.transaction(function (transaction) {
//load data.json
    var dbDefs = dbController.jsonObject(dbController.dbFolder + "data.json")
```

```
//parse array "table"
    eval(dbDefs);
    for(var i in arrTables) {
      createTable(arrTables[i].table, arrTables[i].def, arrTables[i].data);
    }
```

```
//create table
    function createTable(table, arrDef, arrData){
      var arrColumns = [];
      var strSQL = "Create Table " + table + " (";
      for(var j in arrDef) {
        arrColumns.push(arrDef[j].column);
        strSQL += arrDef[j].column + " " + arrDef[j].type + ", ";
      }
      strSQL = strSQL.substring(0, strSQL.lastIndexOf(",")) + ")";
      transaction.executeSql(strSQL, [],
        function() {
          console.log(table + " created.");
          populateTable(table, arrColumns, arrData);
          return;
        },
        dbController.errorHandler
      );
    }
```

```
//populate table
    function populateTable(table, arrColumns, arrData) {
      for (var k in arrData) {
        var arrVal = [];
        var strVal = "";
        for (var l = 0; l < arrColumns.length; l++) {
          strVal += "?,";
          arrVal.push(arrData[k][arrColumns[l]])
        }
        var strSQL = "Insert Into "+table+" (" + arrColumns.toString()+") ";
        strSQL += "Values ("+strVal.substring(0, strVal.lastIndexOf(","))+");";
        transaction.executeSql(strSQL, arrVal, null, dbController.errorHandler);
      }
      console.log("  " + table + " populated.");
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Does your `transaction.executeSQL` expect a flat array (only 1 record), or an array of arrays, each representing a record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm making some assumptions here, but try changing:

```
for (var k in arrData) {
    strVal = "?,";
    arrVal.push(arrData[k]. ~~ KEY VALUE NAME ~~ )
}
var strSQL = "INSERT INTO " + table + " (" + strCol + ") ";
strSQL += "VALUES (" + strVal.lastIndexOf(",") + ");";
```

to:

```
for (var i =0; i < arrColumns.length; ++i) strVal += ',?';
for (var k in arrData)
{
    arrVal[k] = [];
    for (var i in arrColumns) 
        arrVal[k].push (arrData[k][arrColumns[i]]);
}
var strSQL = "INSERT INTO " + table + " (" + strCol + ") ";
strSQL += "VALUES (" + strVal.substr(1) + ");";
```

If I'm correct in thinking that `transaction.executeSql(strSQL, arrVal, null, dbController.errorHandler);` accepts multiple records, then this should work fine. Otherwise, call

```
transaction.executeSql(strSQL, arrVal[0], null, dbController.errorHandler);
```

instead

Answer (score 0):

Don't you just want to look at the first row of your 'data' element and enumerate through those keys (assuming all the rows are the same)?

```
for (var k in arrData[0]) {...
```

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, and time you have an object with members that you can access via `obj.member`, you can also access it as `obj["member"]`. Objects in JavaScript are essentially just hash tables with the ability to call methods on them (which are also just entries in the hash table), and a prototype based inheritance system.

Anyhow, that means that you can use `for ... in` to iterate over the properties in that hash table, and pull out the keys.

So, if I understand what you're trying to do correctly, you could just do something like this (note that the structure of this loop is somewhat different than the one in your question, as you're going to need one `INSERT` statement for each row to insert, while your loop had the construction of the `INSERT` statement outside of the loop over the data rows):

```
function populateTable(table, data) {
    for (var k in data) {
        var queryArgs = [];
        var argArray = [];
        var columns = [];

        for (var col in data[k]) {
            queryArgs.push('?');
            columns.push(col);
            argArray.push(data[k][col]);
        }

        var SQL = "INSERT INTO " + table + " (" + columns + ") VALUES " +
            "(" + queryArgs + ");";
        alert(SQL + " [" + argArray + "]")
    }
}
```

Comment: He has only 1 `INSERT` because he's using a prepared statement (in Javascript!)

Comment: Ah, right. In his original code, he was just executing the query once, rather than actually using a prepared statement for each data value. Part of the problem is that his example function was so incomplete it was hard to tell what he was trying to do. Anyhow, the details of how the query works aren't important, I think he can figure that out, I was just trying to show how the loop could work.